# How to reduce the number of 301 redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

For my website I want to force an URL with https, without www and without .php extension.
For that my htaccess file contains the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

#force HTTPS and remove the www
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.jvincent\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://jvincent.fr/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

#To remove the .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(php-script) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ (.*)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

It works fine.
But if I access to my website using the URL http://www.jvincent.fr/phpinfo.php I have two 301 redirects :

1. http://www.jvincent.fr/phpinfo.php to
   https://jvincent.fr/phpinfo.php
2. https://jvincent.fr/phpinfo.php to https://jvincent.fr/phpinfo

I searched but I was not able to find a solution to optimize and have only one 301 redirect in all cases.
I there a way to do that? Merging all the conditions before an unique RewriteRule? Using environment variable (flag E in the first part)?

Thanks for your help.

Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

#force HTTPS and remove the www
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.jvincent\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:\.php)?$ https://jvincent.fr/$1 [NC,QSA,L,R=301]

#To remove the .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(php-script) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ (.*)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Great!Thanks a lot :)